# get diff of 1d rust ndarray

Tags: rust, rust-ndarray

I feel like this code should work:

```
use ndarray::{Array1, s}; // 0.15.4

fn main() {
    let x = Array1::<f64>::range(0.0, 10.0, 1.0);
    println!("{:?}", x);
    println!("{:?}", x.slice(s![1..]));
    println!("{:?}", x.slice(s![..-1]));
    println!("{:?}", x.slice(s![1..]) - x.slice(s![..-1])); // fails to compile when this line is uncommented
}
```

The first 3 print lines do work if I comment the final print.  Am I missing something here?
[Rust Playground Implementation](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=c4298808635b61e553fae1ce60c98708)

Comment: You can use ` println!("{:?}", &x.slice(s![1..]) - &x.slice(s![..-1]));` since it allows the output of the expression to be of a different type than either of the input arrays. If you use the owned version, it would require that the output be `&f64` which is not possible since it would require the results already exist for a reference to be taken to them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [documentation](https://docs.rs/ndarray/0.12.1/ndarray/struct.ArrayBase.html#arithmetic-operations) explains that:

> Let A be an array or view of any kind. Let B be an array with owned
> storage (either Array or ArcArray). Let C be an array with mutable
> data (either Array, ArcArray or ArrayViewMut). The following
> combinations of operands are supported for an arbitrary binary
> operator denoted by @ (it can be +, -, *, / and so on).
>
> - &A @ &A which produces a new Array
> - B @ A which consumes B, updates it with the result, and returns it
> - B @ &A which consumes B, updates it with the result, and returns it
> - C @= &A which performs an arithmetic operation in place

[And also](https://docs.rs/ndarray/0.12.1/ndarray/struct.ArrayBase.html#slicing):

> You can use slicing to create a view of a subset of the data in the
> array. Slicing methods include .slice(), .slice_mut(), .slice_move(),
> and .slice_collapse().

So you want to use `&x.slice(s![1..]) - &x.slice(s![..-1])` (note the two `&`).